# drop a DataFrame column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I desperately need help here. I am trying to get the dimension of a dataframe. I always get 31 columns instead of 30: Value should be 30, found 31. I tried to reset_index(drop = True) but I still get the same error. any help is appreciated. Stay safe.

```
def read_data(dataset_id):
    data = None
    # Begin CODE
    if dataset_id == 'breast_cancer':
        disease = 'breast_cancer'
        datafile = 'wdbc.data'  

        bc_columns = ['ptid', 'diagnosis', 'mean_radius', 'mean_texture', 
        'mean_perimeter', 'mean_area',
                  'mean_smoothness', 'mean_compactness', 'mean_concavity', 
        'mean_concave_pts', 'mean_symmetry ',
                  'mean_fractal_dim', 'std_err_radius', 'std_err_texture', 
        'std_err_perimeter', 'std_err_area',
                  'std_err_smoothness', 'std_err_compactness', 
        'std_err_concavity', 'std_err_concave_pts',
                  'std_err_symmetry ', 'std_err_fractal_dim', 'worst_radius', 
        'worst_texture', 'worst_perimeter',
                  'worst_area', 'worst_smoothness', 'worst_compactness', 
        'worst_concavity', 'worst_concave_pts',
                  'worst_symmetry ', 'worst_fractal_dim']

        data = pd.read_csv(datafile, skipinitialspace=True, names=bc_columns)

        data.drop(labels=['ptid'], axis=1, inplace=True)

        bc_diag_class = get_class_list_dict(data['diagnosis'])

        elif dataset_id == 'hyperthyroidism':
            disease = 'hyperthyroidism'
            datafile1 = 'allhyper.data'  # tab delimited, no header
            datafile2 = 'allhyper.test'  # comma delimited, no header

    ht_columns = ['age', 'Gender', 'on thyroxine', 'query on thyroxine', 'on 
    antithyroid medication', 'sick',
                  'pregnant', 'thyroid surgery', 'I131 treatment', 'query 
    hypothyroid', 'query hyperthyroid',
                  'lithium', 'goitre', 'tumor', 'hypopituitary', 'psych', 
   'TSH measured', 'TSH', 'T3 measured',
                  'T3', 'TT4 measured', 'TT4', 'T4U measured', 'T4U', 'FTI 
    measured', 'FTI', 'TBG measured', 'TBG',
                  'referral source', 'diag_class']

    data1 = pd.read_csv(datafile1, sep='\t', skipinitialspace=True, 
    names=ht_columns)
    data2 = pd.read_csv(datafile2, skipinitialspace=True, names=ht_columns)

    data = data1.append(data2, ignore_index=True)

    data = data.replace(to_replace='?', value=float('nan'))

    data[['diag_class', 'ptid']] = data['diag_class'].str.split(pat='.\|', 
    expand=True)

    diag_class = data['diag_class']
    data.drop(labels=['diag_class', 'ptid'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    data.insert(0, 'diag_class', diag_class)

    data[['age', 'TSH', 'T3', 'TT4', 'T4U', 'FTI', 'TBG']] \
        = data[['age', 'TSH', 'T3', 'TT4', 'T4U', 'FTI', 
    'TBG']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

        elif dataset_id == 'cervical_cancer':
           disease = 'cervical_cancer'
            datafile = 'risk_factors_cervical_cancer.csv'  

    cc_columns = ('Age', 'Num_sex_partners', 'First_sex_intercourse', 
    'Num_pregnancies',
                  'Smokes', 'Smokes_years', 'Smokes_packs_year', 
    'Hormonal_Contraceps',
                  'Hormonal_Contraceps_years', 'IUD', 'IUD_years', 'STD', 
    'STD_number',
                  'STD_condylomatosis', 'STDscervical_condylomatosis', 
    'STD_vaginal_condylomatosis',
                  'STD_vulvo_perin_condylomatosis', 'STD_syphilis', 
    'STD_pelvic_inflam_disease',
                  'STD_genital_herpes', 'STD_molluscum_contagiosum', 
    'STD_AIDS', 'STD_HIV', 'STD_HepB',
                  'STD_HPV', 'STD_Num_diagnosis', 
   'STD_Time_since_first_diag', 'STDs_Time_since_last_diag',
   'Dx_Cancer', 'Dx_CIN', 'Dx_HPV', 'Dx', 'Hinselmann', 'Schiller', 
    'Citology', 'Biopsy')

    data = pd.read_csv(datafile, skipinitialspace=True)
    data.columns = cc_columns
    data = data.replace(to_replace='?', value=float('nan'))
    biopsy_class = data['Biopsy']
    data.drop(labels=['Dx_Cancer', 'Dx_CIN', 'Dx_HPV', 'Dx', 'Hinselmann', 
    'Schiller', 'Citology', 'Biopsy'],
              axis=1, inplace=True)

    data.insert(0, 'Biopsy', biopsy_class)

    data[['Num_sex_partners', 'First_sex_intercourse', 'Num_pregnancies', 
    'Smokes_years', 'Smokes_packs_year',
          'Hormonal_Contraceps_years', 'IUD_years',
          'STD_number', 'STD_Time_since_first_diag', 
    'STDs_Time_since_last_diag']] \
        = data[['Num_sex_partners', 'First_sex_intercourse', 
   'Num_pregnancies', 'Smokes_years', 'Smokes_packs_year',
                'Hormonal_Contraceps_years', 'IUD_years',
                'STD_number', 'STD_Time_since_first_diag', 
   'STDs_Time_since_last_diag']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

elif dataset_id == 'liver_cancer':
    disease = 'liver_cancer'
    datafile = 'Indian Liver Patient Dataset (ILPD).csv'  # comma delimited, 
     no header
    ld_columns = ['Age', 'Gender', 'TB', 'DB', 'Alkphos', 'Sgpt', 'Sgot', 
    'TP', 'ALB', 'A/G Ratio', 'Selector']

    data = pd.read_csv(datafile, skipinitialspace=True, names=ld_columns)

    data.loc[data['Gender'] == 'Male', 'Gender'] = 'M'
    data.loc[data['Gender'] == 'Female', 'Gender'] = 'F'

    selector_class = data['Selector']
    data.drop(labels=['Selector'], axis=1, inplace=True)

    data.insert(0, 'Selector', selector_class)
    data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
# End CODE
print(data.head(20))
return data


def dimensions(dataset_id, dataset):
    dim = None
    # dim = dataset.shape
    num_inst = len(dataset)
    num_feat = len(dataset.iloc[0].reset_index())
    dim = (num_inst, num_feat)
    return dim
```

Comment: I was trying to edit your post for better code formatting, but boy is it difficult. Can you try formatting your post for better readability and the convenience of fellow SO users?

Comment: Please format your code. It's tough to understand

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop a column from DataFrame, You can do like this.

If you want to drop single column:

```
df.drop(['column_name'], axis = 1)
```

If you want to drop multiple columns:

```
df.drop(['Column1', 'Column2'], axis = 1)
```

If you want to drop based on some other condition instead of column name. You can comment below. I'll update the answer accordingly. Hope it helps!.

Comment: Your question is not readable, please reformat it. Accordingly I will update my answer.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your answer. I want to get rid of the index column. Or maybe this should be considered row index 0...569

Comment: diagnosis  mean_radius  ...  worst_symmetry   worst_fractal_dim
0         M        17.99  ...           0.4601            0.11890
1         M        20.57  ...           0.2750            0.08902
2         M        19.69  ...           0.3613            0.08758
3         M        11.42  ...           0.6638            0.17300
4         M        20.29  ...           0.2364            0.07678

I have something like this. I want to get the dimension of the dataset. It should return 30 columns but I get 31 columns

Comment: For getting rid of index column. You should try the following:
`df = df.reset_index()`